# What preposition goes with "good" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Here's a sentence from a test:

> To be honest, there aren't many things Serena isn't good ___.

What preposition should I use after 'good'? I think both 'at' and 'with' are possible. Can I also use 'in'?

Which would be the most natural to say for a native speaker? (The test only accepts one answer.)

Comment: While R Mac lists the prepositions 'good' often colligates with, the only one sounding natural (in terminal position) here is 'at'.

Comment: In everyday language that means 'combines with', which is the standard grammatical expression for denoting the adjoining of a preposition and the word it complements.

Answer (score 1):

One may be good *with* nouns, indicating that one is proficient at use of the noun.

"Suzy is good with the cello."
"Eddy is good with a paint brush."
"Lauren is good with engines."

One may be good *at* a noun which is a gerund or when using the word "that" to refer to an activity.

"Patrick is good at [playing] baseball."
"Emily is good at carving pumpkins."
"Fitzgerald is good at that."

One may be good *in* a place--but only if the activity in question (at which one is good) is implied--or in a role (for instance, when acting).

"Jessica is good in the driver's seat."
"Derek is good in the field."
"Lesley is good in villain roles."